# How to safely assert that no shared preferences are present

Tags: android, caching, preferences, assert, sharedpreferences

I tried to find out how to safely assert that preferences aren't stored anywhere. It seems that haven't understood the caching mechanism yet and the docs don't clarify it. This is what I did:

```
File prefsFile = new File("/data/data/"+context.getPackageName() + "/shared_prefs/"
    + context.getPackageName() + "_preferences.xml");
prefsFile.delete();
assertFalse(prefsFile.exists()); // success

// This assertion could fail - why?
assertEquals(0, context.getSharedPreferences(context.getPackageName()+"_preferences",
    MODE_PRIVATE).getAll().size());
```

Although I deleted the prefs file, it is still possible that `getAll().size()` returns a non-zero value.

Could someone explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried to find out how to safely assert that preferences aren't stored anywhere.

Why?

> Could someone explain why?

Off the top of my head:

- You are not actually testing to see if the file exists before deleting it, or if the directory exists
- You are hard-coding a path that may not be correct on all devices
- You are assuming that deleting a file deletes the in-process copy of the `SharedPreferences`
- You are not bothering to look at the `HashMap` returned by `getAll()` to see if your data is there, or if it is some system-supplied initial values

If you want to clear out `SharedPreferences`, do not try deleting the file. Either call `edit().clear().commit()` or `edit().clear().apply()` on your `SharedPreferences` object.

Comment: Thanks for the post! So the SharedPreferences instance is indeed to also copy/cache the persisted prefs and doesn't simply provide a reference (i.e. like a java.io.File object).To the first point: delete() simply returns false if the file doesn't exist so why do a check? So you'd only test on the in-process copy of the prefs?

Comment: "So the SharedPreferences instance is indeed to also copy/cache the persisted prefs" -- yes. In fact, it doesn't like it if you mess with the file behind its back. "delete() simply returns false if the file doesn't exist so why do a check?" -- because you're not examining the return value from `delete()`. "So you'd only test on the in-process copy of the prefs?" -- I'd use the actual API. If you clear the prefs and commit the changes, it will clear the contents of the file.

Comment: Well, I didn't want to check if the file existed before deletion or was deleted, I just wanted to make sure it doesn't exist - nothing more! Just one question: What kind of system-supplied initial values could have been written to the file?

Comment: I follow your advice and don't mess with the file. There should really be no need to do that.

Comment: "What kind of system-supplied initial values could have been written to the file?" -- AFAIK, there aren't any. I was simply pointing out a flaw in your logic there. :-)